# Creating correct for-loop/iteration for a unique list

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop, iteration

I have a list of the numbers 1,2,3 and 4.

I wish to print them out in the following manner:

```
1
2
3
4
11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24
31
```

..and so on.

How is it possible to do?
Thanks

Comment: no clue yet. trying to do it somehow

Comment: And so on, into infinity? You want to include 1413123421234132422341224432111234223314132 in that sequence?

Comment: It's a basic thing you can find it in python docs.

Comment: No existing in python docs.. It's more of mathmatics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

maximumDigits = 2
digits = '1234'
for l in range(1, maximumDigits + 1):
    for n in product(digits, repeat=l):
        print(''.join(n))
```

Gives you:

```
1
2
3
4
11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24
31
32
33
34
41
42
43
44
```

Non-itertools solution:

```
>>> digits = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> nums = newNums = list(digits)

# calculate 2-digit numbers
>>> newNums = [n * 10 + m for n in newNums for m in digits]
>>> nums.extend(newNums)
>>> nums
[1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 31, 32, 33, 34, 41, 42, 43, 44]

# calculate 3-digit numbers
>>> newNums = [n * 10 + m for n in newNums for m in digits]
>>> nums.extend(newNums)
>>> nums
[1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 31, 32, 33, 34, 41, 42, 43, 44, 111, 112, 113, 114, 121, 122, 123, 124, 131, 132, 133, 134, 141, 142, 143, 144, 211, 212, 213, 214, 221, 222, 223, 224, 231, 232, 233, 234, 241, 242, 243, 244, 311, 312, 313, 314, 321, 322, 323, 324, 331, 332, 333, 334, 341, 342, 343, 344, 411, 412, 413, 414, 421, 422, 423, 424, 431, 432, 433, 434, 441, 442, 443, 444]

# this repeats for each new digit you want
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wish to try and achieve this without "itertools"

Comment: Hey poke, Thanks for answering. Would you mind explaining what happens in [n * m 10 + m for n in newNums for m in digits]? I cannot understand m's meaning

Comment: `m` will be one of `(1, 2, 3, 4)` while `n` will be one existing number previously calculated. So for example with `n = 23`, this will do `23 * 10 + m` for those four values of `m`. So you get `231`, `232`, `233`, and `234`.